# Partial view that does not use the ActionName that I specify

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am currently developing an application in C # with ASP.NET MVC and entity Framework.

I use a partialview to edit data, for example I have a list of "module" in table form, I can add a module, delete one or edit one.

To create a module I proceed as follows:

My view :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ModuleUpdatePanel" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
     <!-- Modal -->
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
          <div class="modal fade" id="ModuleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModuleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                         @Html.Action("_CreateModule")
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The controller's method returning the partialview inside my modal:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult _CreateModule()
{
    ModuleViewModel ViewModel = new ModuleViewModel { };
    return PartialView(ViewModel);
}
```

The partialview :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateModule", "Parametres", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @model Lynx.ViewModels.ModuleViewModel
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModuleModalLabel">
            Ajouter un module
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Module.Libelle_Module, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Libellé du module" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Module.Libelle_Module)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Module.Capacite_Max_Module, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Capacité max (Palettes/heure)" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Module.Capacite_Max_Module)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Annuler
        </button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enregistrer" />
    </div>


}
```

The controller's method adding the module:

```
[Authorize]
[ActionName("CreateModule")]
public void CreateModule(Modules module)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (Dal.GetModule(module.PK_Code_Module) == null)
    {
        Dal.AddModule(Dal.GetMaxIdModule() + 1, module.Libelle_Module, module.Capacite_Max_Module);
    }
  }
}
```

For this part, everything works. Where I have a problem is at the level of my module edition (I use the same process)

View :

```
<div class="modal-content">
     @Html.Action("_EditModule", "Parametres", new { id = @module.PK_Code_Module })
</div>
```

The controller's method returning the partialview inside my modal:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult _EditModule(int Id)
{
    Modules module = Dal.GetModule(Id);
    return PartialView(module);
}
```

The PartialView :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditModule", "Parametres", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @model Lynx.Models.Modules

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="EditModuleModalLabel">
            Modifier un module
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
            <b>Id Module</b>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PK_Code_Module, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Libellé</b>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Libelle_Module, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <b>Capacité max du module (colis/heure)</b>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Capacite_Max_Module, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Annuler
        </button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enregistrer" />
    </div>
}
```

The controller's method Editing the module:

```
[Authorize]
[ActionName("EditModule")]
public void EditModule(Modules module)
{
    if (Dal.GetModule(module.PK_Code_Module) != null)
    {

        Dal.UpdateModule(int.Parse(module.PK_Code_Module), module.Libelle_Module, module.Capacite_Max_Module);
    }

    String URL = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    string[] lines = Regex.Split(URL, "/");
    if (lines[lines.Length - 1] == "Parametres")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Parametres");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Index");
    }
}
```

Here my button "Enregistrer" does absolutely nothing ... As if he ignored my "Bginform"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Put [HttpPost] in the action on your controller. Like that:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ActionName("EditModule")]
public void EditModule(Modules module)
{
    if (Dal.GetModule(module.PK_Code_Module) != null)
    {

        Dal.UpdateModule(int.Parse(module.PK_Code_Module), module.Libelle_Module, module.Capacite_Max_Module);
    }

    String URL = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    string[] lines = Regex.Split(URL, "/");
    if (lines[lines.Length - 1] == "Parametres")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Parametres");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
I just have a problem with the first element of my array (where it still does not do anything)

Comment: I tried something else, adding a @using html.beginform around the button calling my modal. It works on all my records, without the [HttpPost] tag.
It sounds suspicious, but it works ... But it seems suspicious